# Please could someone check my proof that continuous implies locally Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-continuity

I have produced a false proof but can't spot the mistake.

I proved the following (false) statement:

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be open and $f: U \to \mathbb R^n$ be continuous. Then $f$ is locally Lipschitz.

Note that this statement is false as continuity does *not* imply local Lipschitzness.

> Please could someone tell me where I my mistake is?

Here is my false proof:

The goal is to show that for a point $u \in U$ there is an open set containing $u$ on which $f$ is Lipschitz. So let's pick some $u$ in $U$. Since $U$ is open there exists some open ball $B = B(u,r)$ such that the closure of $B$ is also contained in $U$:

$$ u \in \overline{B} \subseteq U$$

Since $f$ is continuous and $\overline{B}$ is compact, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\overline{B}$. That is, for every $L > 0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that

$$ |x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)|<L$$

Fix $L=1$ (an arbitrary choice!) and pick $\delta' $ to be smaller than $\min(r, \delta,1)$. Then $B(u, \delta')$ is contained in $B(u,r)$.

Then $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $L$ on $B(u,\delta')$:

If $x,y \in B(u, \delta')$ then $\|f(x) - f(y)\| < 1 < 1\cdot \|x-y\| = L \|x-y\|$.

Comment: What is $\varepsilon$ here -- shouldn't it be $L$? Also, Lipschitz-ness would require that $\lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert \leq L\cdot \lvert x-y\rvert$, which can be much smaller that $L$ -- and your proof only guarantees the latter.

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you, that was a typo! I have corrected it.

Comment: I also found another typo which I also corrected.

Comment: @astudent What about he second remark? Even with your choice of $\delta^\prime$, this does not prove $\lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert \leq L\lvert x -y \rvert$ on $B(u,\delta^\prime)$... you only get $\lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert \leq L$.

Comment: @ClementC. Oh, you are right. But I think it can be fixed: we could pick $\delta' < 1$.

Comment: No matter the choice of $\delta^\prime$: $x$ and $y$ could be arbitrarily close, so no matter what $L$ you have on the RHS, it will not be tight enough: that is, you get $\leq L$ instead of $\leq L\lvert x-y\rvert$... the RHS you obtain can be much bigger than the one you have to guarantee for the Lipschitz condition.

Comment: You're not even using the fact that *for all* $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ etc - just that for some *for some* $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0.$ Let's get concrete: Suppose we're on $[0,1]$ and we have an arbitrary function $f$ defined there subject only to the condition that  $|f(x)|\le 1$ for all $x\in [0,1].$ This $f$ can be pretty wild, but still for all $x,y\in [0,1],$ we have $|x-y| < 2$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|< 3.$ Why would that imply anything about $f$ being Lipschitz, or even continuous?

Comment: Another thing: Since $L$ can be arbitrarily small, you've "shown" that $f$ is locally Lipschitz with any Lipschitz constant whatsoever, no matter how small. That will be news to some functions, like $f(x)=x.$

Comment: Thank you, I just saw you comments now. I will study them now.

Comment: @ClementC. I'm sorry I still don't understand. Concretely, if $\delta'$ is also smaller than $1$ then the RHS will be less than $L$ which is less than $L \|x-y\|$ (if $\|x-y\| < 1$. What am I missing? (I tried to make this step clearer in the question (I am not trying to convince people here that it's correct, I am just trying to understand why it's wrong)

Comment: @zhw. Good points, I don't know why bounded would imply Lipschitz. :-( But I'm still puzzled by my proof :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct up to $\|f(x) - f(y)\| < 1$. It fails at the next step, as the inequality $1 < 1\cdot \|x-y\|$ is false in general.

Getting the factor of $\|x-y\|$ in this estimate is the essence of Lipschitz continuity. And you don't have it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I chose $\delta'$ to be $<1$. So we have $\|x-y\|< 1$. Why does this not imply
$ 1 < 1 \cdot \|x-y\|$?

Comment: The inequality looks the wrong way.

Comment: Hahahaha, I am stupid! This is the most stupid mistake I made in a long time! Thank you for your help!